# Extending a basic web crawler to filter status codes and HTML

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, web-crawler, http-status-codes

I followed a tutorial on writing a basic web crawler in Java and have got something with basic functionality.

At the moment it just retrieves the HTML from the site and prints it to the console.
I was hoping to extend it so it can filter out specifics like the HTML page title and the HTTP status code?

I found this library:
http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/
... which I think might be able to do the job for me but could I do it without using an external library?

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // String representing the URL
    String input = "";

    // Check if argument added at command line
    if (args.length >= 1) {
        input = args[0];
    }

    // If no argument at command line use default
    else {
        input = "http://www.my_site.com/";
        System.out.println("\nNo argument entered so default of " + input
                + " used: \n");
    }
    // input test URL and read from file input stream
    try {

        testURL = new URL(input);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                testURL.openStream()));

        // String variable to hold the returned content
        String line = "";

        // print content to console until no new lines of content
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception thrown");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely tools out there for HTTP communication.  However, if you prefer to implement one yourself - look into java.net.HttpURLConnection.  It will give you more fine grained control over HTTP communications.  Here's a little sample for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
  URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

  connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

  String resp = getResponseBody(connection);

  System.out.println("RESPONSE CODE: " + connection.getResponseCode());
  System.out.println(resp);
}

private static String getResponseBody(HttpURLConnection connection)
    throws IOException
{
  try
  {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        connection.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder responseBody = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
      responseBody.append(line + "\n");
    }

    reader.close();
    return responseBody.toString();
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep - "connection.getResponseCode();" worked a treat for the HTTP status code.
Thanks again.
On to extracting the HTML title page now...

Comment: The page title only comes from the HTML - so you will have to parse that out of the response body manually.

Comment: Another thing puzzling me is how to limit the speed of the crawler.
Only thing I could find on here was this, which recommends it but doesn't say how:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701313/web-crawler-performance

Comment: Thread.sleep(ms) will make the current thread sleep the specified length of time.  That's one way to throttle the crawling.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeff.
I've run into another problem regarding the specifics of parsing but I'll post another question.

Comment: Another thing with this, it only crawls the main page.
Any idea how easy it would be to make it crawl every page of a site?

Comment: you would have to parse out links/anchor tags from the HTML and then "visit" those too

Comment: Thank you again.
I'll try to tackle that tomorrow.